# If $X \geq X_t$ why is $\frac{X}{(1+|X|)} \geq \frac{X_t}{(1+|X_t|)}$? So a monotone, 1-1 transformation doesn't affect the inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am wondering why if $X=\sup_t \{ X_t \} $ for $t \in T$ which is some index set, we have that $\frac{X}{1+|X|} \geq \frac{X_t}{1+|X_t|}$.

Clearly, $ \ast X \geq X_t \forall t$.

My beginning is to write $\frac{X}{1+|X|} \geq \frac{X_t}{1+|X|}$ and then I was trying to manipulate the denominator. For instance, if $|X_t| \geq |X|$ which is one the two cases stemming from $\ast$, then it's easy to see but the other way round?

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+|x|}$ has derivative $\frac{1}{(1 + |x|)^2} > 0$ and is therefore monotone on the whole real line. The assertion follows directly from this.

Comment: Oh wow true! Do you think there is also a way to show this just by manipulating the inequality? Thank you @Dominik

Comment: It is possible, but unnecessary complicated. First note that you can assume that either $X$ and $X_t$ are positive or both negative [else the inequality holds trivially]. If they are positive, the inequality is equivalent to $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{X}} \ge \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{X_t}}$, which is true. If both are negative, you can approach it in a similar way.